# probability of selecting from a team

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I cannot fully understand this question and my answer is way different from how things should work

> Q>> a basketball team consists of 3 positions(guard-forward-centre)
>
> if 3 people are selected randomly from 3 of such teams
>
> i) .. what's the probability of selecting a complete team?
>
> ii).. what's the probability of selecting the three with the same
>   position?

====my answer====

i)3^3/9C3

ii)3C1*3C1*3C1/9C3

====modal answer====

> i)3!*((1/3)^3)
>
> ii)3*((1/3)^3)

Comment: Is this the exact wording of the question?  Are we selecting three of the nine people or one person from each of the three teams?

Answer (score 0):

Hints

Pick them out one by one.

i) If you picked out e.g. a guard as first then what is the probability that the second will not be a guard? And if this indeed happens then what is the probability that the third  will complete the team?

ii) If you picked out e.g. a guard as first then what is the probability that the second will also be a guard? And if this indeed happens then what is the probability that the third will also be a guard?

Answer (score 0):

$P(\text{event}) = \frac{\text{no. of favourable ways for event to happen}}{\text{total number of possibilities}}$.

There are 3 possible selections from each team. Thus the total number of possibilities $= 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3$. Among all selections, the favourable selections are ones where we have any permutation of  $(\text{guard, forward, centre})$. This gives us a total of $3!$ favourable possibilities. Thus the answer is $\frac{3!}{3^3}$.

Do the same for the second part of the problem. The total number of possibilities are again $3^3$. The number of favourable ways for the event is $3$. Thus is because it can be either $guard, guard, guard$, or $forward, forward, forward$ or $centre, centre, centre$. The answer now is $\frac{3}{3^3}$.

Comment: but why can't the total number of possibilities be 9C3?

Comment: Because $9C3$ counts the number of ways you can select three things among 9 things. This is not what we want to count.

Repetitions are allowed in this case. Thus it is 3 * 3 * 3.